# Como executar .jar com o prompt?

Tags: java, windows, jar

Já gerei o arquivo jar pelo Netbeans, mas não estou conseguindo fazer a execução do programa pelo prompt de comando.

Qual o comando para executá-lo em ambiente Windows?

Answer (score 13):

Use o comando:

```
java -jar arquivo.jar
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Ou simplesmente dê um clique duplo sobre o arquivo .jar!

Comment: Erro: Nao e possivel localizar nem carregar a classe principal...

Comment: Teste com um helloWorldSimples.jar. Se ainda não funcionar, tente reinstalar o JRE (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Quando a versão instalada do java é inferior à versão do jar, este erro é exibido. Instale uma versão mais recente do java.

Answer (score 8):

Para criar um JAR executável é necessário que o `Manifest.mf` do mesmo informe o nome completo (pacote.Classe) da classe que contém o método `main()` que deve ser executado. Verifique se este é o caso. Abra o JAR (pode ser com um programa Unzip) e veja o conteúdo de `META-INF/Manifest.mf`. Ele deve conter a seguinte linha em algum lugar, com o pacote/nome da sua classe executável.

```
Main-class: nome.do.pacote.ClasseExecutavel
```

Além disso é necessário que a classe executável esteja lá (veja em nome/do/pacote tem uma `ClasseExecutavel.class`)

Outro problema que pode fazer com que o seu JAR não rode é a falta de dependências. Se o seu código tiver dependências, ele pode funcionar no NetBeans e não funcionar em linha de comando se você não informar o CLASSPATH das dependências (JARs, diretórios, etc.) Você pode gerar um JAR contendo todas as dependências, ou executar o JAR informando o Classpath:

```
java -cp dependencia.jar:/tmp/dependencias -jar app.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

**Depende do jar**
Existem dois tipos de jar:

- O **jar** executável

Esse é fácil é só você executar:

`java -jar  meuJar.jar`

- O **jar** pacote

  Esse jar pode ser executado mas não nasceu pra isso então a forma de executa-lo é diferente, você precisa dizer qual é a classe executável(a classe que tem o método **main**) ex:

  ```
  // OlaMundo.java
  import javax.swing.*;
  public class OlaMundo {
          public static void main(String args[]){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Olá mundo");
      }
  }



  # compilando e rodando    
  javac OlaMundo.java
  jar cf olamundo.jar OlaMundo.class
  # no linux
  rm OlaMundo.class
  :: no windows
  del OlaMundo.class
  java -cp olamundo.jar OlaMundo
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que pelo erro apresentado, que indica que a classe principal não foi definida, a resposta do @helderdarocha é a que procura:

> Para criar um JAR executável é necessário que o Manifest.mf do mesmo informe o nome completo (pacote.Classe) da classe que contém o método main() que deve ser executado. Verifique se este é o caso.

[No NetBeans isso é ainda mais fácil, editando as "Propriedades" do projeto.](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup_pt_BR.html#deploy-args)

É pouco provável que a JVM ou suas configurações que estejam com problemas, até porque consegue executar o comando no Prompt e ele retorna um erro bem claro.