# O que permite o Java descobrir qual é a classe principal em um .jar

Tags: java, classes, jar

Como o Java faz pra descobrir qual é classe principal em um arquivo `.jar`

Comment: Acho que estas respostas podem ser peculiares a você:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4964/como-executar-jar-com-o-prompt

Answer (score 4):

Ele não descobre.

O `.jar` normalmente inclui um arquivo chamado `Manifest.mf` que fica dentro da pasta  `META-INF` e que contém uma linha que indica qual é a classe executável, semelhante a essa:

```
Main-class: nome.do.pacote.ClasseExecutavel
```

Como o @Techies informou, ela deve conter esse método:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
```

e deve ficar na pasta `nome/do/pacote/ClasseExecutavel.class`.

(Tirado de: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4995/357)

Answer (score 1):

Quando desenvolvemos um sistema em Java temos que ter um ponto de inicio. Imagine um sistema onde você tem centenas de classes e milhares e métodos. Temos que começar de algum lugar certo?

É por isso que a **JVM**(*Java virtual machine*) irá procurar pelo método `MAIN` em seu sistema.

De forma resumida, a classe que principal é aquela que contem essa instrução:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
```

[Aqui](http://www.htmlstaff.org/ver.php?id=6703) tem um artigo onde talvez voce possa entender melhor.