# Arquivos .jar não abrem

Tags: java

Olá gostaria de uma ajuda, criei um projeto básico em java mas o arquivo .jar não abre.

- já tenho o jdk intalado

> Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation.
>   Todos os direitos reservados.
>
> C:\Users\Leo>java -version java version "1.8.0_121" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

- Já criei um path pro java
- clique duplos não abrem o arquivo
- java -jar tbm não acontece nada.
- tentei abrir outros arquivos .jar e nada

Já nao sei mais oque tentar galera.

Comment: Qual IDE você utilizou?

Comment: Boas, a resposta do [helderdarocha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4897/helderdarocha) a esta pergunta: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4964/como-executar-jar-com-o-prompt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4964/como-executar-jar-com-o-prompt) poderá ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Você esqueceu de indicar sua classe main no jar. A flag 'c' indica que você quer criar um novo arquivo jar e 'f' o nome do arquivo.

> O sinalizador 'e' (para 'entrypoint') cria ou substitui o Main-Class atributo do manifesto. Ele pode ser usado durante a criação ou atualização de um arquivo JAR. Use-o para especificar o ponto de entrada do aplicativo sem editar ou criar o arquivo de manifesto.

```
jar cfe arquivo.jar foo.Main foo/Main.class foo/Outra.class
```

Fonte: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html